# Recibir datos desde una clase en segundo Activity

Tags: java, android

Estoy enviando una llave con un id a una segunda activity donde se reciben las llaves y de acuerdo al id se dibuja un objeto geométrico el problema es que al recibir los datos no los puedo utilizar en el `onDraw()` :

esta es la clase que envia los datos:

```
@Override
public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

    return new RecyclerViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerViewHolder recyclerViewHolder, int posicion) {

    recyclerViewHolder.txt1.setText(figuras[posicion]);
    recyclerViewHolder.txt2.setText(detalles[posicion]);
    recyclerViewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(listaFigura[posicion]);
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    recyclerViewHolder.cardView.setTag(recyclerViewHolder);

}

View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        RecyclerViewHolder vh = (RecyclerViewHolder) view.getTag();
        int posicion = vh.getAdapterPosition();

        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Tablero.class);

            //view.getContext().startActivity(intent);

        switch (posicion){
            case 0:
                intent.putExtra("KEY", 1);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "texto 0: "+posicion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 1:
                intent.putExtra("KEY", 2);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "texto 1: "+posicion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(context, "texto 2: "+posicion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(context, "texto 3: "+posicion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(context, "texto 4: "+posicion, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
```

y aquí esta la que recibe:

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tablero);

        Lienzo lienzo = new Lienzo(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(lienzo);

        RelativeLayout contenedor = findViewById(R.id.contenedor);
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablero, contenedor, true);

        Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        int ID = datos.getInt("KEY");

    }
}
```

Esta es la clase en la cual deseo obtener el valor del ID:

```
class Lienzo extends View{

    public static int llave;
    float x = 200;
    float y = 200;
    int id = 0;
    Path path = new Path();
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Lienzo(Context context){
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(40, 133, 255));
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        path.addCircle(x, y, 50, Path.Direction.CCW);
    }
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){

        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            x =event.getX();
            y =event.getY();
        }
        invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En este caso el valor de ID lo necesitas en la clase `Lienzo`, lo puedes realizar modificando el constructor de la clase `Lienzo` para que reciba este valor:

```
class Lienzo extends View{

public static int llave;
float x = 200;
float y = 200;
int id = 0;
Path path = new Path();
Paint paint = new Paint();

public Lienzo(Context context, int ID){
    super(context);
    paint.setColor(Color.rgb(40, 133, 255));

    //asigna el valor de ID
    this.id = ID;
}
...
...
...
}
```

Ahora de esta forma lo puedes enviar a tu clase Lienzo:

```
@Override 
 protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.tablero);

    Bundle datos = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    int ID = datos.getInt("KEY");        

   //Instancia Lienzo y envia el valor de ID.
   Lienzo lienzo = new Lienzo(getApplicationContext(), ID);
   setContentView(lienzo);

   RelativeLayout contenedor = findViewById(R.id.contenedor);
   LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
   View inf = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablero, contenedor, true);    
}
```